# Getting identity value while inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `ID` which is auto increment and another column `Request_Number`

In `Request_Number` i want to insert something like `"ISD0000"+ID` value...
e.g For the first record it should `ID 1` and Request_Number "`ISD000001`"

How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to *store* this information? - it seems like it can always be trivially (re-)computed.

Comment: Does the _Request_Number_ really need to relate to the _ID_ column? If you just need a unique, non-changeable _Request_Number_ you could use the solution that was removed: INSERT ... SELECT 'ISD0000' + STR(MAX(ID))...

Comment: thanks Josien...i would have tried your solution as a back up...it was preferable to use the identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a computed column:

```
create table T
(
  ID int identity primary key check (ID < 1000000),
  Request_Number as 'ISD'+right('000000'+cast(ID as varchar(10)), 6)
)
```

Perhaps you also need a check constraint so you don't overflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your table definition already in place you can alter the column and add Computed column marked as persisted as:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename drop column Request_Number;
ALTER TABLE tablename add Request_Number as 'ISD00000' + CAST(id  AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED ;
```

If computed column is not marked as persisted, it is not created when the column is created, in fact it is still computed at run time. Once you mark column as persisted, it is computed right away and stored in the data table.

[Edit]:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename drop column Request_Number;
ALTER TABLE tablename add Request_Number as 'ISD' 
+right('000000'+cast(ID as varchar(10)), 6) PERSISTED ;
```

Comment: Yes it will but i would like to ask why won't it?? any reason.. that i'm missing??

Comment: it is not that you miss something .. actually the thing i was not knowing that this can be done.
+1 for teachng me this

Comment: another thing was...is it possible to control the number of 0's prepended...as in if it is 1 digit...prepend it by 5 0's if 2 digit like 11, prepend it with 4 0's

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE T
(       ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
        Request_Number AS 'ISD' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)), 6),
    CONSTRAINT PK_T_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a103e8/1)**

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
UPDATE dbo.TableName
SET Request_Number = 'ISD' + RIGHT('00000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),ID),6)
WHERE Request_Number IS NULL
```

Assuming that you want to update this table, but you can modify it easily for a trigger or insert.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'ISD0000'+CONVERT(varchar, IDENT_CURRENT('Tablename'))
```

Comment: When using `CONVERT` and `varchar`, you should **always** define a **length** for the `varchar` - how long is this `varchar` of yours going to be, maximum?

Comment: Actually there is no limit specified in question.If i have not mentioned size it can be incriment from 0 to maximum character limit of varchar.

Comment: Yes yes - but **how long** is your `varchar` going to be, if you don't specify a length?? If you use `CONVERT(varchar(10), ..` it's clear - 10 characters maximum. But if you use `CONVERT(varchar, ...` without a length - what do you expect - how long can the resulting `varchar` be??? Don't rely on luck or defaults - **specify** a length, then it's clear what you're doing!

Comment: Hey you just look into my query.I am converting an integer value to varchar.I think you can imagine the limit and output.IDENT_CURRENT function return identity value of table.conversion is needed when it is appending on varchar value..

Comment: @marc_s is completely right here. Aaron Bertrand has written about this on [sqlblog.com](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). Assuming ID is an INT then it can be no longer than `VARCHAR(10)` so this is a safe bet. It is also variable length so you don't actually lose anything if you declare it as `VARCHAR(10)`, `SELECT LEN(CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(10)))` still gives a result of 1, but it is much safer and much more legible.